Modification of exam `answer plot` to allow drawing partial opacity when `\printanswers` is uncommented
Following up on this question and this question regarding "answer plots" for the exam class, I am running into an issue. I have a region shading at less than 100% opacity. If I try adding the answer plot style to this plot:

\printanswers commented: plot correctly hidden (opacity set to 0),
\printanswers uncommented: plot incorrectly fills at 100% opacity instead of 20% opacity.


\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %for graphing/plotting functions http://sites.clas.ufl.edu/gma/files/tikz.pdf
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows.meta,automata,backgrounds,bending,calc,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,matrix,patterns,positioning,quotes}

\tikzset{
  answer/.style={draw,text opacity=0},
  answer plot/.style={opacity=0},
}
\let\oldprintanswers\printanswers
\def\printanswers{
    \oldprintanswers%
    \tikzset{answer/.style={text opacity=1}, answer plot/.style={opacity=1}}
}

\printanswers

\begin{document}

% Example TikZ picture
Reflection over $y$-axis:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \begin{axis}
        [
            % legend pos=outer north east,
            grid,
            xmin=-3, xmax=3,    ymin=-3,    ymax=3,
            % xlabel = {$x$}, ylabel = {$y$},
            xtick={-2,-1,...,2},
            ytick={-2,-1,...,2},
            xticklabels={-2,,0,,2},
            yticklabels={-2,,0,,2},
            clip=false, 
            grid = major, axis lines = middle,
            axis line style={gray}
        ]
            \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (i) at (1,0);
            \coordinate (j) at (0,1);
            \coordinate (Ai) at (-1,0);
            \coordinate (Aj) at (0,1);

            % Line of Symmetry
            \draw[line width=1pt, dashed, cyan]($(0,-3)$)--($(0,3)$) node[xshift=-1.5em, yshift=1em]{$x=0$};
    
            %Original
            \draw [ultra thick, draw=none, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.2] (o) -- (i) -- ($(i)+(j)-(o)$) -- (j) -- cycle;
            \draw[line width=1pt, blue, -latex](o)--(i) node[midway, xshift=0em, yshift=-1em]{$\vec{\bm{i}}$};
            \draw[line width=1pt, blue, -latex](o)--(j) node[midway, xshift=1em, yshift=0em]{$\vec{\bm{j}}$};
            \draw[line width=1pt, blue, -latex, dashed](o)--($(i)+(j)-(o)$) node[midway, xshift=2em, yshift=2em]{$\vec{\bm{i}}+\vec{\bm{j}}$};
            

            %Transformed
            \draw [ultra thick, draw=none, fill=red, opacity=0.2, answer plot] (o) -- (Ai) -- ($(Ai)+(Aj)-(o)$) -- (Aj) -- cycle;
            \draw[line width=1pt, red, -latex, answer plot](o)--(Ai) node[midway, xshift=0em, yshift=-1em]{$\bm{A}\vec{\bm{i}}$};
            \draw[line width=1pt, red, -latex, answer plot](o)--(Aj) node[midway, xshift=-1em, yshift=0em]{$\bm{A}\vec{\bm{j}}$};
            \draw[line width=1pt, red, -latex, dashed, answer plot](o)--($(Ai)+(Aj)-(o)$) node[midway, xshift=-2em, yshift=2em]{$\bm{A}\paren{\vec{\bm{i}}+\vec{\bm{j}}}$};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}

Is there some adjustment we can make to respect the original opacity (in this case, of 20%), when \printanswers is uncommented?

You are using opacity=0 to hide anwers and opacity=1 to show them.  There are other ways to do this.  Easiest is to use \phantom to hide it.

BTW, your MWE is not executable.

Thanks. Fixed MWE.

I added a temporary workaround solution for now. If you think there's a better way using \phantom, feel free to post an answer and let me know. Thanks.

You can use \if \else \fi inside a tikzpicture.  \printanswers sets \ifprintanswers.
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\bm#1{\mathbf{#1}}
\def\paren#1{(#1)}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %for graphing/plotting functions http://sites.clas.ufl.edu/gma/files/tikz.pdf
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows.meta,automata,backgrounds,bending,calc,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,matrix,patterns,positioning,quotes}

\printanswers

\begin{document}

% Example TikZ picture
Reflection over $y$-axis:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \begin{axis}
        [
            % legend pos=outer north east,
            grid,
            xmin=-3, xmax=3,    ymin=-3,    ymax=3,
            % xlabel = {$x$}, ylabel = {$y$},
            xtick={-2,-1,...,2},
            ytick={-2,-1,...,2},
            xticklabels={-2,,0,,2},
            yticklabels={-2,,0,,2},
            clip=false, 
            grid = major, axis lines = middle,
            axis line style={gray}
        ]
            \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (i) at (1,0);
            \coordinate (j) at (0,1);
            \coordinate (Ai) at (-1,0);
            \coordinate (Aj) at (0,1);

            % Line of Symmetry
            \draw[line width=1pt, dashed, cyan]($(0,-3)$)--($(0,3)$) node[xshift=-1.5em, yshift=1em]{$x=0$};
    
            %Original
            \draw [ultra thick, draw=none, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.2] (o) -- (i) -- ($(i)+(j)-(o)$) -- (j) -- cycle;
            \draw[line width=1pt, blue, -latex](o)--(i) node[midway, xshift=0em, yshift=-1em]{$\vec{\bm{i}}$};
            \draw[line width=1pt, blue, -latex](o)--(j) node[midway, xshift=1em, yshift=0em]{$\vec{\bm{j}}$};
            \draw[line width=1pt, blue, -latex, dashed](o)--($(i)+(j)-(o)$) node[midway, xshift=2em, yshift=2em]{$\vec{\bm{i}}+\vec{\bm{j}}$};
            

          \ifprintanswers\begin{scope}
            \draw [ultra thick, draw=none, fill=red, opacity=0.2] (o) -- (Ai) -- ($(Ai)+(Aj)-(o)$) -- (Aj) -- cycle;
            \draw[line width=1pt, red, -latex](o)--(Ai) node[midway, xshift=0em, yshift=-1em]{$\bm{A}\vec{\bm{i}}$};
            \draw[line width=1pt, red, -latex](o)--(Aj) node[midway, xshift=-1em, yshift=0em]{$\bm{A}\vec{\bm{j}}$};
            \draw[line width=1pt, red, -latex, dashed](o)--($(Ai)+(Aj)-(o)$) node[midway, xshift=-2em, yshift=2em]{$\bm{A}\paren{\vec{\bm{i}}+\vec{\bm{j}}}$};
          \end{scope}\fi
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
Is there some adjustm


Here's a solution I came up with that defines two styles, answer plot and answer fill. It does the trick for now. Let me know if you think there's a better way.

\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows.meta,automata,backgrounds,bending,calc,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,matrix,patterns,positioning,quotes}

% Define a custom macro to control the answer fill opacity
\newcommand{\answerfillopacity}{0}

% Define the answer styles
\tikzset{
  answer/.style={draw,text opacity=0},
  answer plot/.style={opacity=0},
  answer fill/.style={opacity=\answerfillopacity}
}

% Redefine \printanswers to change opacity settings
\let\oldprintanswers\printanswers
\def\printanswers{%
  \oldprintanswers%
  \renewcommand{\answerfillopacity}{0.2}%
  \tikzset{
    answer/.style={text opacity=1},
    answer plot/.style={opacity=1}
    }%
}

% Uncomment the following line to show answers
\printanswers

\begin{document}

% Example TikZ picture
Reflection over $y$-axis:
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
            \begin{axis}
            [
                % legend pos=outer north east,
                grid,
                xmin=-3, xmax=3,    ymin=-3,    ymax=3,
                % xlabel = {$x$}, ylabel = {$y$},
                xtick={-2,-1,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,...,2},
                xticklabels={-2,,0,,2},
                yticklabels={-2,,0,,2},
                clip=false, 
                grid = major, axis lines = middle,
                axis line style={gray}
            ]
                \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (i) at (1,0);
                \coordinate (j) at (0,1);
                \coordinate (Ai) at (-1,0);
                \coordinate (Aj) at (0,1);
    
                % Line of Syemetry
                \draw[line width=1pt, dashed, cyan]($(0,-3)$)--($(0,3)$) node[xshift=-1.5em, yshift=1em]{$x=0$};
        
                %Original
                \draw [ultra thick, draw=none, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.2] (o) -- (i) -- ($(i)+(j)-(o)$) -- (j) -- cycle;
                \draw[line width=1pt, blue, -latex](o)--(i) node[midway, xshift=0em, yshift=-1em]{$\vec{\bm{i}}$};
                \draw[line width=1pt, blue, -latex](o)--(j) node[midway, xshift=1em, yshift=0em]{$\vec{\bm{j}}$};
                \draw[line width=1pt, blue, -latex, dashed](o)--($(i)+(j)-(o)$) node[midway, xshift=2em, yshift=2em]{$\vec{\bm{i}}+\vec{\bm{j}}$};
                
    
                %Transformed
                \draw [ultra thick, draw=none, fill=red, answer fill] (o) -- (Ai) -- ($(Ai)+(Aj)-(o)$) -- (Aj) -- cycle;
                \draw[line width=1pt, red, -latex, answer plot](o)--(Ai) node[midway, xshift=0em, yshift=-1em]{$\bm{A}\vec{\bm{i}}$};
                \draw[line width=1pt, red, -latex, answer plot](o)--(Aj) node[midway, xshift=-1em, yshift=0em]{$\bm{A}\vec{\bm{j}}$};
                \draw[line width=1pt, red, -latex, dashed, answer plot](o)--($(Ai)+(Aj)-(o)$) node[midway, xshift=-2em, yshift=2em]{$\bm{A}\paren{\vec{\bm{i}}+\vec{\bm{j}}}$};
    
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}

